# C++ / C# PInvoke - Marshalling explicitly sized numerics

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling

if I wish to marshal an `int` in C# (`Int32`) to/from a native (C++) library, what's the best way to declare the relevant variable in C++ code?

I could use a standard `int` but I'd rather be explicit about the width of that variable (I know that it's 32-bit on most platforms anyway).

So far, I can see two options:

- `int32_t` in *<cstdint>*
- `__int32` (MSVC++ identifier) ... However I'd like to remain platform independent if I can

I seem to recall hearing that C++11 has some new library for this, but I can't seem  to find any mention of it.

Thank you.

Comment: int32_t seems a decent option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *int* keyword in the currently shipping C# and C++ compilers are *type aliases*,  respectively for System.Int32 and __int32, the concrete types used by their back-ends.  I've been writing code for 30 years and have used 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit processors.  And used *int* 30 years ago like I do today.  And expended very little effort to port programs to the next generation architecture or operating system version.

You see this back in the winapi as well.  Every type used for a function argument or return value is a type alias.  The CreateWindow() function in Windows version 1.0 looks *exactly* the same as the one you use in the 64-bit version of Windows 8.1

I have no illusion that this progression suddenly stopped today.  128-bit processors are already the bread-and-butter for IBM.  Languages use type aliases to prevent themselves from becoming rapidly outdated and forgotten.  True for languages like C and C++, true for C# as well.  Although it certainly is going to require moving a bigger rock in the case of C#, the identity is engraved in most any C# programmer's mind right now.

Intentionally *not* using type aliases makes your program *less* portable.

Comment: In C++ int is not a type alias for __int32

Comment: It most certainly is in the Microsoft compiler.  Someday it will be something else, __int64 perhaps.

Comment: Sure. But you did not say that. You said "in the C++ language".

Answer (score 0):

You can use int32_t which is exactly 32 bits. It is possible for there to be a C++ implementation for which int32_t is not defined, but in that case, all bets are off.

On every platform that I know of which supports C#, then C/C++ int is 32 bits and so you may be over-thinking this.

Another thing to consider is what type your C++ code accepts. If it accepts int, and you use a platform where int is not 32 bits, then you still have a problem.